# Bottom Navigation Activity в комбинации с Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

как в одной из вкладок Bottom Navigation Activity сделать Tabbed Activity?
Я пытался найти в интернете, но кроме картинок с тем что мне нужно я ничего не находил. Мне желательно увидеть как выглядит полный проект, что бы я смог понять его структуру.
[image: Как должно быть]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать табы как на вашей картинке вы можете воспользоваться `ViewPager`.
Возможно вам будет проще посмотреть в формате видео. 
Вот официальный пример от Google: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ

Пример настоящего проекта: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ